# How to parse a multi-parameter function from Python Config file?

Tags: python, config

I am trying to use a multi parameter function in a Python config file. The problem arises when I try to call it in to the script and then cast the parameters as ints. Is there a way to do this in python?

```
#Config File-----------------------------------

[Camera_Settings]
SENSOR-TAP = 1
ROI = 640,320,8,6

#Python Script--------------------------------

#! /usr/bin/python

import configparser
import serial

List_of_Camera_Commands = []            

# Establish serial port
'''
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
print(ser.name)
ser.baudrate = 192000
ser.write(stuff to write)
ser.read()
'''

CameraConfig = configparser.ConfigParser()
CameraConfig.read("CameraConfig.conf")        #Read in Config File

#---------Code to read in Config file Options and cast as   ints---------------


for name in CameraConfig.options('Camera_Settings'):                            
Casted_Int_Values = CameraConfig.getint('Camera_Settings', name)           

print(name, ": ",Casted_Int_Values)                                         

Temp_command = [name,  Casted_Int_Values]                                   

List_of_Camera_Commands.append(Temp_command)                              

print(List_of_Camera_Commands)                                                 

#ser.write(List_of_Camera_Commands)       ------> write to serial????







#output = invalid literal for int() with base 10: '640,320,8,6
```

Answer (score 0):

The ROI variable isn't a int but a string containing multiple int.  You are probably getting the first one though.

Try to split ROI on mutiple line.  Or expect ROI to be a string that can be split on comma and then used on the int() to convert to an int.  :)

Try doing this before your for loop to see what the value is looking like before taking it as a int.

```
for name in CameraConfig.options('Camera_Settings'):
    print(name, CameraConfig.get('Camera_Settings', name))
```